# Creating, Using and Discarding Temporary Value not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am trying to assign a ViewState value in my application with a SelectedIndexChanged function. Once it's assigned the postback will use the value to change some data and then set the value to zero but I can't seem to get it to work correctly. The controls are all created dynamically on Page_Load.

**Page Load**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateAttributeControls();
    TempProductVariantId = 0;
}
```

**Create Attribute Controls**

```
public void CreateAttributeControls()
{
    ...
    var ddlArtistArtworks = new DropDownList();
    ddlArtistArtworks.ID = "ddlArtistArtworksTest";
    divAttribute.Controls.Add(ddlArtistArtworks);
    ddlArtistArtworks.Items.Clear();
    ddlArtistArtworks.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ArtistArtwork_SelectedIndexChange);
    ddlArtistArtworks.AutoPostBack = true;
    ...
}
```

**ArtistArtwork_SelectedIndexChange**

```
protected void ArtistArtwork_SelectedIndexChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = sender as DropDownList;
    TempProductVariantId = int.Parse(ddl.SelectedValue);
}
```

**TempProductVariantId ViewState Save**

```
public int TempProductVariantId
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["TempProductVariantId"] == null)
            return 0;
        else
            return (int)ViewState["TempProductVariantId"];
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["TempProductVariantId"] = value;
    }
}
```

**When I load the page everything is fine. I change the DropDownList's value, It posts back, and the value is not set. Change it again the value is set and continues to change as I change the value of the `DropDownList`.**

Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I have tried changing when `CreateAttributeControls()` is called. In `OnPreRender` for example. I was given this to understand the lifecycle of the page [Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are essentially recreating the dropdown on every postback..

try this

```
public void CreateAttributeControls()
{
    ...
    DropDownList ddlArtistArtworks;
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ddlArtistArtworks = new DropDownList();
        ddlArtistArtworks.ID = "ddlArtistArtworksTest";
        divAttribute.Controls.Add(ddlArtistArtworks);
        ddlArtistArtworks.Items.Clear();
        ddlArtistArtworks.AutoPostBack = true;
    }
    else
    {
         ddlArtistArtworks = (DropDownLise)divAttribute.FindControl("ddlArtistArtworksTest");
    }

    ddlArtistArtworks.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ArtistArtwork_SelectedIndexChange);
    ...
}
```

For dynamically added controls, the event handler has to be linked up everytime so that has to be done outside the if-block, unconditionally.

Comment: Hmmm.. The `ddlArtistArtworks` is a grandchild of a different control.  Everytime the Page_Load is called the upmost parent is cleared. This still doesn't explain why it will not work the first time but all other times I change the dropdown it does.

Comment: @brenjt when you recreate a control, it loses the selection (and it's state).

Comment: For that reason I am saving it in the ViewState via this call: `TempProductVariantId = int.Parse(ddl.SelectedValue);`

Comment: @brenjt still; when there is a postback, the page load is executed and then the control event. You are destroying the control and recreating it in page load; so by the time it gets to the control event, `ddl.SelectedValue` is not valid.

Comment: Okay, you are right. I did try creating the controls via the PreRender function since it loads after the control event but I got the same results. Any tips on that? I also tried calling it in the SelectIndexChanged function.

Comment: @brenjt Generally, you create controls and do databinding just once. Since viewstate is enabled by default (and you have it enabled too), these controls maintain state b/w postbacks. When you are adding hierarchy of dynamic controls, you have to keep it going for all controls in the order of parent to children. Hope that helps! I'm sure there's lot more code to this and I'm not able to get the complete picture with the snippets from the post.

Comment: I used a recursive function to find the correct control then I did as you said and assigned the EventHandler which then called the SelectIndexFunction. All before it was replaced. Thank you much.